# Show multiple great circles on mapbox with turf.js

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

I am trying to add multiple great circle lines between the markers in the same map container. I managed to show one with [`greatCircle`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#greatCircle) in turf.js.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2 ;i++) {

    var getStart = json.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];
    var getEnd = json.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1];

    //console.log(getStart) 
    //console.log(getEnd)

    var start = turf.point(getStart);
    var end = turf.point(getEnd);

    var data = turf.greatCircle(start, end);

    console.log(data) 
}
```

Is it possible to list all of them and applying Turf.js?

Here is my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/micheldb/pwLk8e43/2/).

Comment: Sorry, list all of what? What do you mean "multiple trajectories"?

Comment: Hi Steve, yes all of the trajectories listed in the geojson and apply greatCircle on each of them. See als the JsFiddle.

Answer (score 5):

Give `map.addSource` a new `FeatureCollection` where the features are the great circles from the turf function. There is a [helper function](http://turfjs.org/docs/#featureCollection) in turf for that.

I've included the logic of your loop in a function that returns a `FeatureCollection` of great circles:

```
function getGreatArcFc() {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < json.features.length; i++) {
    var feature = json.features[i];
    var getStart = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
    var getEnd = feature.geometry.coordinates[1];
    var start = turf.point(getStart);
    var end = turf.point(getEnd);
    data.push(turf.greatCircle(start, end));
  }
  return turf.featureCollection(data);
}

map.on('load', function() {
    map.addSource('route', {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": getGreatArcFc()
    });
  map.addLayer({
    "id": "route",
    "source": "route",
    "type": "line",
    "paint": {
      "line-width": 1,
      "line-color": "#000000"
    }
  });
});
```

[Updating your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhtgLowc/) with that logic gives:

[image]

It's a bit hard to make out in the screenshot, but there are separate great circles between what I see as London to NY and London to Boston maybe ?

Comment: Hi Robin, this is really good and exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Feel free to accept/ upvote if it met your requirement - there's a green tick button you can click